# tqslcert won't load my tq6 certificate

Tags: paid-applications

I have installed Ubuntu on my XP workshop desktop PC. I installed Trustedqsl from the Ubuntu software center. However tqslcert doesn't manage the tq6 certificate that I used in XP.

How do I get a P12 certificate?

Answer (score 1):

I went to Tqsl in XP, saved a P12 certificate and then successfully loaded it in the Ubuntu Tqslcert and It fixed the issue.